# Is it possible to modify a store from another store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux with multiple reducers combined into `rootReducer`. How is it possible to modify the state of one reducer from another reducer? Ex:

```
// systemReducer.js
const INITIAL_STATE = { isLoggedIn: true }
function systemReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) { 
    switch(action.type) { ... }
}

// messagesReducer.js
const INITIAL_STATE = { messages: [] }
function messagesReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) { 
    switch(action.type) { ... }
}
```

And then say I have action makers for messagesReducer as under:

```
// messageActions.js
export const messagesFetchAction = (data) => {
    return {
        type: MESSAGES_FETCH,
        data: data
    }
}
```

Now, how can I modify `systemReducer`'s `isLoggedIn` to `false` from `messagesFetchAction()`? So it looks like as under for example:

```
// messageActions.js
export const messagesFetchAction = (data) => {
    systemState.setState({isLoggedIn: false});     // <=====
    return {
        type: MESSAGES_FETCH,
        data: data
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you'll have to check for that action in the rootReducer and return the modified root state.

Comment: See [Structuring Reducers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two reducers does not mean that you have several stores. You still have single store, but combined from two reducers. In general, your store may look like:

```
{ 
    systemReducer: {
        isLoggedIn: true
    },
    messagesReducer: {
        messages: []
    }
}
```

You couldn't dispatch action from reducer. This is prohibited by redux. But you may dispatch several actions from action creator. For example:

```
export const messagesFetchAction = (data) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: LOGGED_IN, isLoggedIn: false});    
    dispatch({
        type: MESSAGES_FETCH,
        data: data
    });
}
```

The action creator above is for [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk). To be able to use it, apply middleware when creating store like this

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    systemReducer,
    messagesReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware
));
```

Comment: All should I have known that I could dispatch a login action from `messagesFetchAction` file... Thanks @Fyodor